# how to convert a value to hhmm format when it has no leading zeros in pig latin script

Tags: python, apache-pig

I am trying to find difference between two different time fields in pig relation . I can use todate() method of pig but for that it should be in hhmm format. However it does not have leading zeros. For example if the two field had value 1245 and 1425 I can find the difference converting them using todate. However if the value is 945 and 823 then I cannot convert using todate because there is no leading zero.

However I wrote a python udf attempting to leftpad a zero. Please find the code below

```
 @outputSchema("time:bytearray")


def zero(time):
        time = str(time)
        if len(time)<= 3:
                return '0'+ time
        else:
                return time
```

Step 1 : Registered my python function

```
REGISTER '/home/Jig13517/zeropad.py' using jython AS myfuncs ;
```

Please find the relation below

```
Airlines_data_schema = LOAD '/user/Jig13517/pigsample/Airlines_data.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek,DepTime_actual,CRSDeptime,Arrtime_actual,CRSArrtime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum_Plane,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,Airtime,Arrdelay,Depdelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,Taxiin,Taxiout,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay);
```

=====================================

Then I tried to leftpad the column value with zeros

```
airlines_new = FOREACH Airlines_data_schema GENERATE Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek,myfuncs.zero($4) AS DepTime_actual_new,myfuncs.zero($5) AS CRSDeptime_new,myfuncs.zero($6) AS Arrtime_actual_new,myfuncs.zero($7) AS CRSArrtime_new,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum_Plane,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,Airtime,Arrdelay,Depdelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,Taxiin,Taxiout,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay ;
```

===============================

Sample data after application of python udf

```
 (2008,1,3,4,617,615,652,650,WN,11,N689SW,95,95,70,2,2,IND,MCI,451,6,19,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,None,None,None,None,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
```

But we can see above it is not converting the column value . I am getting the same fields unaltered. Please let me to know what is wrong with my udf or is there any any pig method to achieve this task.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] of your input. We don't need to see all 30+ columns of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.zfill) function could help

input.txt

```
1245
1425
945
823
```

pig_udfs.py

```
@outputSchema('time:chararray')
def lpad_time(time):
    return time.zfill(4)
```

time_formatter.pig

```
register pig_udfs.py using jython as myfuncs;
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage();
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $0);
\d B
```

Output

```
(1245)
(1425)
(0945)
(0823)
```

Obviously, you could make Python do the entire `todate` function itself...

Also, I wasn't clear in your question if the minutes were zero padded.

---

**EDIT**

airlines.csv

```
2008,1,3,4,617,615,652,650,WN,11,N689SW,95,95,70,2,2,IND,MCI,451,6,19,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,None,None,None,None,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

pig code

```
register pig_udfs.py using jython as myfuncs;
A = LOAD 'airlines.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS Year, $1 AS Month, $2 AS DayofMonth, $4 AS DayofWeek,myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $4) AS DepTime_actual_new,myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $5) AS CRSDeptime_new,myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $6) AS Arrtime_actual_new,myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $7) AS CRSArrtime_new,$8 AS UniqueCarrier,$9 AS FlightNum,$10 AS TailNum_Plane,$11 AS ActualElapsedTime, $12 AS CRSElapsedTime, $13 AS Airtime, $14 AS Arrdelay, $15 AS Depdelay, $16 AS Origin, $17 AS Dest, $18 AS Distance, $19 AS Taxiin, $20 AS Taxiout, $21 AS Cancelled, $22 AS CancellationCode, $23 AS Diverted, $24 AS CarrierDelay, $25 AS WeatherDelay, $26 AS NASDelay, $27 AS SecurityDelay, $28 AS LateAircraftDelay ;
\d B
```

Output

```
(2008,1,3,617,0617,0615,0652,0650,WN,11,N689SW,95,95,70,2,2,IND,MCI,451,6,19,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
```

Comment: Minutes were not zeropadded, my intention is to make all of them uniform(i.e) . If the filed has 1245 then its fine if its 845 then make it 0845. Logic is if it has 4 digits then leave it as is. If its three digit then left pad a zero.

Comment: Isn't that what my answer does? But really, minutes aren't padded? How are you supposed to tell `01:09` from `00:19`?

Comment: Ok my mistake probably I was not clear. I wanted  the format to be hhmm where 945 should be ideally 0945. Yes hours and not minutes should be padded. I still face the same issue. it is not getting converted. If you see the 4th ,5th,6th and 7th column it is still not padded.                                                                                                        (2008,1,3,4,628,620,804,750,WN,448,N428WN,96,90,76,14,8,IND,BWI,515,3,17,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,None,None,None,None,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)

Comment: Are you looking at my answer? Values clearly are padded... I don't know what you are doing wrong, sorry

Comment: I tried with your file it is working but with mine it is returning none value.

Comment: Your previous comment is showing non-padded values, not None, so what did you change?

Comment: As I commented above, if you create a [mcve] (as my answer) you may be able to see the error better.

Comment: For example, you never needed to `LOAD AS` with a schema. You can rename it later after the `GENERATE`, so use `myfuncs.lpad((chararray) $6) AS Arrtime_actual`, for example.

Comment: When I  just used "FOREACH A GENERATE myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $0);" it is giving me none.                     And when I include all the fields along with this such as "airlines_new = FOREACH Airlines_data_schema GENERATE Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek,myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $4) AS DepTime_actual_new,myfuncs.lpad_time((chararray) $5) AS CRSDeptime_new,myfuncs.lpad_time(Arrtime_actual) AS Arrtime_actual_new,myfuncs.lpad_time(CRSArrtime) AS CRSArrtime_new,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum".     It is not converting the fields. Sorry for not intending it is not allowing me to intend.

Comment: I think the indentation in your UDF is bad, then as Python functions return `None` as default

Comment: `'2008'.zfill(4)` definitely doesn't return `None`

Comment: I got the problem. When I did "print leftpad_time(999)" at the end of code it gave me 0999 which means the code and indentation is good but the column value is not passed to function as arguement . Need to figure out why.

Comment: I got it working it is passing the filed value but it doesnt actually change the value it changes the value lke this :  (2008,1,3,4,array('b', [54, 49, 55]),array('b', [54, 49, 53]),array('b', [54, 53, 50]),array('b', [54, 53, 48]),WN,11,N689SW,95,95,70,2,2,IND,MCI,451,6,19,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
in place of ('b', [54, 49, 55]) we should get 0617 just wondering why it is converting it to array.

Comment: @user7699179 Sorry, I have no idea what you are doing wrong... My answer works fine, and I just updated it with your inputs to prove it

Answer (score 0):

Hey @cricket_007 I got it working.I was passing the column fields as bytearray that was the mistake I was doing. Then when I changed the schema to chararray then it started padding zero. Thanks a lot.
Please find the corrected records below:

```
(2008,1,3,4,0617,0615,0652,0650,WN,11,N689SW,95,95,70,2,2,IND,MCI,451,6,19,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
(2008,1,3,4,0628,0620,0804,0750,WN,448,N428WN,96,90,76,14,8,IND,BWI,515,3,17,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
```